# how to flow type array of objects with object keys as string and values of mixed type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

how to flow type array of objects with object keys as string and values of mixed type?

```
example : [
        {"appId":13118,"id":100,"a":"hey","b":-1,"c":null,"d":0,"e":true}
]
```

for now I am doing this as 
example: Array<{[string] : $ANY}>

is it possible to define acceptable types for any here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Flow syntax for [objects as maps](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps).

```
const example : Array<{[string] : mixed }> = [
  { "appId": 13118, "id": 100, "a": "hey", "b": -1, "c": null, "d": 0, "e": true }
]
```

As a side note, in JavaScript object keys are always strings, so you don't need to put quotes around the keys:

```
const example : Array<{[string] : mixed }> = [
  { 
    appId: 13118,
    id: 100,
    a: "hey",
    b: -1,
    c: null,
    d: 0,
    e: true
  }
]
```